# javascript prop( checked, true) not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2, pjax

I have a list of checkbox, on many pages, when I move from one page to other I need to check if any checkbox is in temporary table, if it is to mark it like checked.

```
$(document).on('click','.page a',function (){
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
        var p = $(this).attr('data-page'); 
        //console.log(p);
        x = i + 20 * p;
        if (keys.indexOf(x) > -1) {
            $(':input[value="'+x+'"]').prop('checked',true);
            console.log(x);
        } 
    };
});
```

After I click on next page (where I clicked before on checkbox) I see checked checkbox_id( in this line console.log(x); ) but they are not checked when I get to the page. The result look like [this.](http://prntscr.com/ba77fr) 
For display I use yii2 gridview between tags Pjax.

Comment: You don't seem to preventDefault action for event. Does that mean that page reloads? If so, checkboxes will not be checked on new page (unless you will pass information from previous page somehow).

Comment: No. The page is not reloaded(acording to documentation it is sending just Pjax request to server).  But if you are right what should I do to avoid this situation. Tx.

Comment: If ajax indeed sends data to server, then maybe library automatically updated your view, along with checkboxes? Sorry, i never used Pjax and used yii only briefly. Try to use browser debugger, and see what happens with your changes to HTML. If they are checked and then again unchecked, that would mean some automagic stuff from library updates them.